# What scalability issues are associated with NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, social-networking, libraries

I'm interested in network analysis on large networks with millions of nodes and tens of millions of edges.  I want to be able to do things like parse networks from many formats, find connected components, detect communities, and run centrality measures like PageRank.

I am attracted to NetworkX because it has a nice api, good documentation, and has been under active development for years.  Plus because it is in python, it should be quick to develop with.

In a recent presentation (the slides are available on github [here](https://github.com/drewconway/NetworkX_Intro_Materials)), it was claimed that:

> Unlike many other tools, NX is designed to handle data on a scale
>   relevant to modern problems...Most of the core algorithms in NX rely on extremely fast legacy code.

The presentation also states that the base algorithms of NetworkX are implemented in C/Fortran.

However, looking at the source code, it looks like NetworkX is mostly written in python.  I am not too familiar with the source code, but I am aware of a couple of examples where NetworkX uses numpy to do heavy lifting (which in turn uses C/Fortran to do linear algebra).  For example, the file `networkx/networkx/algorithms/centrality/eigenvector.py` uses numpy to calculate eigenvectors.

Does anyone know if this strategy of calling an optimized library like numpy is really prevalent throughout NetworkX, or if just a few algorithms do it?  Also can anyone describe other scalability issues associated with NetworkX?

**Reply from NetworkX Lead Programmer**
I posed this question on the NetworkX mailing list, and Aric Hagberg replied:

> The data structures used in NetworkX are appropriate for scaling to
>   large problems (e.g. the data structure is an adjacency list).  The
>   algorithms have various scaling properties but some of the ones you
>   mention are usable  (e.g. PageRank,  connected components, are linear
>   complexity in the number of edges).
>
> At this point NetworkX is pure Python code.  The adjacency structure
>   is encoded with Python dictionaries which provides great flexibility
>   at the expense of memory and computational speed.  Large graphs will
>   take a lot of memory and you will eventually run out.
>
> NetworkX does use NumPy and SciPy for algorithms that are primarily
>   based on linear algebra.  In that case the graph is represented
>   (copied) as an adjacency matrix using either NumPy matrices or SciPy
>   sparse matrices.  Those algorithms can benefit from the legacy C and
>   FORTRAN code that is used under the hood in NumPy and SciPY.

Comment: It seems I have trouble inspecting the source myself at the moment. But in any case, consider: 80% of the time may be spent in 20% of the code. Mercurial is written *mostly* in Python, yet I haven't heard a single person complain about its speed compared to Git, which is mostly C.

Comment: Yes, but I am also worried about memory. The graph representation in networkx is a python library.  Will that mean that I can fit only smaller graphs into memory?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your big issue will be memory. Python simply *cannot* handle tens of millions of objects without jumping through hoops in your class implementation. The memory overhead of many objects is too high, you hit 2GB, and 32-bit code won't work. There are ways around it - using slots, arrays, or NumPy. It *should* be OK because networkx was written for performance, but if there are a few things that don't work, I will check your memory usage.

As for scaling, algorithms are basically the only thing that matters with graphs. Graph algorithms tend to have *really* ugly scaling if they are done wrong, and they are just as likely to be done right in Python as any other language.

Answer (score 28):

This is an old question, but I think it is worth mentioning that [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de) has a very similar functionality to NetworkX, but it is implemented in C++ with templates (using the Boost Graph Library), and hence is much faster ([up to two orders of magnitude](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance)) and uses much less memory.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of graph-tool.

Comment: I tried graph-tool. It really is way faster but kind of ugly to use. The API doesn't feel pythonic.

Comment: True... Just wanted to share my experience with the people here.

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto - is your library suitable for handling ~3M nodes and ~10M edges? I'm guessing the storage is memory only, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can easily handle that with any laptop.

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto why is there such little support for a native windows install?

Comment: @user1938107 It requires substantial changes to the library, and I don't even have a Windows machine.

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto I see, well if you could overcome the library changes i would just buy you a windows machine

Comment: @user1938107 I would rather pay you 10 cents to install a proper operating system on yours...

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto it just costs a few billion more to get companies to develop their software on linux instead of windows :)

Comment: Is graph-tool still faster than NetworkX in 2019? Is the project abandoned? The [git-hub page](https://github.com/antmd/graph-tool) of graph-tool was last updated 4 years ago (its [website](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) is also not quite updated, e.g., the Git link is broken, the change log is not readable etc).

Comment: @opt C++ is still orders of magnitude faster than pure Python in 2019, so the answer is yes. The project is not abandoned at all. That github page is not the official one, is just some random fork. The website is quite up to date and so is the gitlab page.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that networkX is mostly written in python does not mean that it is not scalable, nor claims perfection. There is always a trade-off. If you throw more money on your "machines", you'll have as much scalability as you want plus the benefits of using a pythonic graph library.

If not, there are other solutions, ( [here](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) ), which may consume less memory ( benchmark and see, I think igraph is fully C backed so it will ), but you may miss the pythonic feel of NX.

Comment: That partly answers my question.  But I also want to know if many of the "core" algorithms of NetworkX are implemented in C/Fortran, as claimed.

Comment: I investigated a little the (current) source code, and I found no C/Fortran implementations. It seems that everything in there is pure python...

Comment: thanks for taking a look. Remember that if numpy is called, then (depending on the system configuration) numpy might use LAPACK or other optimized linear algebra packages.  I'm not too familiar with how often NetworkX actually uses numpy (that's sorta my question), but I am aware of a couple examples.  For example, the in networkx/networkx/algorithms/centrality/eigenvector.py uses numpy to find eigenvectors.

Comment: Chiming in as the author of igraph, one of the libraries cited above. The core of igraph is implemented in ~90% C and ~10% C++, and I've handled graphs with ~2 million nodes and ~7 million edges without problems using igraph. It has a Python interface so you can use it from Python, but due to its C legacy, the Python API is not as elegant as that of NetworkX. For instance, nodes and edges are always identified by integers in igraph (since it's much easier to handle on the C level), and you have to use vertex/edge attributes to map them to your actual objects.

Comment: @Tamás You could pickle python data and pass C a buffer a bytes containing the pickled data. Then C could pass back the pickled data to Python to be unpickled. That way, even dictionaries could be passed to C. C wouldn't be able to interact with the data, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GraphScope](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope) can address the scalability problem of NetworkX very well, by offering Python interfaces that are compatible with NetworkX and an efficient distributed runtime implemented in C++. That is, users only need to modify their NetworkX applications with a few lines of code, while achieving several orders of magnitude performance improvement. In a nutshell, running NetworkX applications on GraphScope has the following advantages:

**Minimal user effort:** To make NetworkX applications run on GraphScope, users only need to replace `import network` with `import graphscope.nx as networkx`, since the graph manipulation and data loading interfaces of GraphScope are fully compatible with NetworkX. For example, to run the clustering algorithm in NetworkX, user can write

```py
import os
import network

g = networkx.read_edgelist(
     os.path.expandvars('PATH_TO_DATASET')
)

result = networkx.clustering(g)
```

To run the clustering algorithm on GraphScope, users only need to modify one specific line of code.

```py
import os
import graphscope.nx as networkx

g = networkx.read_edgelist(
     os.path.expandvars('PATH_TO_DATASET')
)

result = networkx.clustering(g)
```

**High performance:** The runtime of GraphScope is implemented with C++ for high efficiency. Taking the above clustering algorithm as an example, running it on GraphScope is over 29x faster than running over NetworkX. Furthermore, GraphScope enables running NetworkX applications in a distributed manner, allowing for high scalability. To run NeteorkX applications in a distributed fashion on a K8s cluster, users need to replace `import graphscope.nx as nwtworkx` with

```py
import graphscope
networkx = graphscope.session(num_workers=$NUM_WORKERS).nx()
```

For more information about how to run NetworkX applications on GraphScope, please check out [Analyzing graph with GraphScope in the Style of NetworkX](https://graphscope.io/blog/tech/2023/06/13/Analyzing-Graph-with-GraphScope-in-the-Style-of-NetworkX).

Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.